# How to query XMLHttpRequest's method type?

Tags: javascript, http, networking, xmlhttprequest

Given an XMLHttpRequest, how can I discover its request method? This would be useful for callbacks to get context about the original call.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('post', 'http://example.com', true)
xhr.??? // should return 'post'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard property that tells you what the type of the request is, unfortunately. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) | [spec reference](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-xmlhttprequest)

---

A couple of options suggest themselves:

1. Give yourself a wrapper
2. Wrap `XMLHttpRequest` itself and add an expando property, but *test test test* on your target browsers.

Example of #1:

```
function xhr(method, url, done) {
    var x = {
        method: method,
        xhr: new HTMLHttpRequest()
    };
    x.method = method;
    x.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.xhr.readyState == 4) {
            done(x, x.xhr.status == 200 ? x.xhr.responseText : null);
        }
    };
    x.xhr.open(method, url);
    return x;
}
```

(Or do a version that returns a promise instead.)

Example of #2 (but *test test test*):

```
(function() {
    var real = XMLHttpRequest;

    XMLHttpRequest = function() {
        var rv = new real();
        rv.open = function(method) {
            rv.method = method;
            return rv.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        return rv; // Overrides the standard result of new XMLHttpRequest
    };
})();
```

I'm not recommending that. :-) A wrapper is much more flexible and reliable cross-browser.

Comment: That's what I found, which is very surprising to me in the era of XHR 2. Still, I'll see if anyone has a cunning hack.

Comment: @mahemoff: I was also surprised. I've added a couple of options for you, btw.

Comment: In my case, I was using a jQuery Rails link, so I ended up just looking at the link that triggered it. Pretty lame :) Something like `$(ev.target).data.method=='post'`